# Displaying files from Storage in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

How to display images uploaded to Storage on view using Blade.

I am trying:
On view:

```
<img class="thumbnails" src="images/qqq3.png" alt="{{ $img->name }}">
```

In routing:

```
Route::get('images/{filename}', function($filename){
    dd($filename);   
});
```

but routing like this is not call

Comment: You have uploaded the images to storage folder and created the symbolic link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make symlink from storage folder to public folder

run this command from your root project folder

```
php artisan storage:link
```

And you can access the files

Comment: I did that and when exploring the folder, the shortcut exists and works, but when I use `Storage::url($user->avatar)` to refer to the actual file, it doesn't work. I've tried to open just the image on the browser, but I still can't get it. the `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161` is returned

Just for clarification, my image is stored in app\storage\defaults\avatars\default_male.png and the url produced for the image is http://192.168.10.10/storage/defaults/avatars/default_male.png

Comment: try to dd($user->avatar); That image path should be /defaults/avatars/default_male.png

Comment: I did, the path isn't the problem, but Laravel still doesn't show it and throws an error instead

Comment: I will make a test now and let you know

Comment: It worked! As said in this post (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/storage-symlink-returning-notfoundhttpexception), appears that since I'm using homestead, I need to create the symlink directly on vagrant via ssh, or I suppose that at least I was supposed to execute the `php artisan storage:link` on vagrant's unix side

Answer (score 0):

To make and image or file public you should upload them on **public** folder. If you want to put a image on your **src="yourcontenthere base64"** you should read image from storage and encode on base64 and put your content to your **src=""**